# Bluetooth mouse cant connect after reboot

Tags: mouse, bluetooth

I have Microsoft Sculpt BT Mouse , I could set up my mouse , and it worked , but  after reboot ,it's not working anymore  I clicked connect under the bluetooth menu with my touchpad , but it cant connect.

I looked [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/53377/bluetooth-mouse-not-auto-reconnecting/53384) but my config already like that.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out this problem with using bluetooth manager (blueman).You can install blueman  if you have this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Also check that you are not affected by this bug
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bluez/+bug/1094744

Answer (score 0):

If you are using bluez, this solution might help you as well as it helped me:

> Basically you need to put your mouse in discoverable mode and then run the following commands in the console:
>
> ```
> hcitool scan
> bluez-simple-agent hci0 XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
> bluez-test-device trusted XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX yes
> bluez-test-input connect XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
> ```
>
> Where XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX is your mouse Bluetooth MAC address as given by hcitool scan.

All credits to this post: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bluez/+bug/1094744/comments/14

Answer (score -1):

i coded a python script to connect bluethooth automatic at startup ,
https://github.com/icesx/ubuntu-autobluetoothmouse-py