# Lenovo IdeaPad 100 Bluetooth doesn't detect any devices RTL8723BE

Tags: bluetooth, lenovo, ideapad

I have a Bluetooth mouse I would like to pair with my IdeaPad, but Bluetooth doesn't detect any devices.

Adapter model: RTL8723BE.

Ubuntu 16.04.

IdeaPad 100.

Mouse: Microsoft Sculpt Comfort Mouse.

My Windows 10 laptop immediately detected the mouse.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way try to install new Bluetooth manager i recommend `blueman-manager` i faced the same problem before it's not only connecting mouse it's also not pairing with any device or sending files.
for more information and another solution take a look at these links [link1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/486347/bluetooth-mouse-not-auto-reconnecting-to-laptop) or [this one](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/177998/bluetooth-mouse-disconnects)

Comment: I tried blueman, doesn't work either

Comment: have you open links?