# Bluetooth Mouse / Keyboard disconnect constantly (Ubuntu 18.04)

Tags: 18.04, keyboard, mouse, bluetooth, logitech

I removed my mouse (Logitech M525) and keyboard (Logitech K380) from `Settings --> Bluetooth`, because it didn't work and I thought I could add it again afterwards, but this was not the case.

I tried it via `CLI --> bluetoothctl`. If I press a key on the keyboard or move the mouse, I see the following:

```
[CHG] Device 34:88:5D:4A:69:F4 Connected: yes
[CHG] Device 34:88:5D:4A:69:F4 Connected: no

[CHG] Device 34:88:5D:89:5A:88 Connected: yes
[CHG] Device 34:88:5D:89:5A:88 Connected: no
```

So it connects but disconnects instantly again, so it is not possible to use it. Also `connect 34:88:5D:4A:69:F4` doesn't work and shows me:

```
[bluetooth]# connect 34:88:5D:4A:69:F4
Attempting to connect to 34:88:5D:4A:69:F4
Failed to connect: org.bluez.Error.Failed
```

Here is what happens when I move the mouse:

[image]

I already tried:

- to disable / enable it from the bios.
- set UserspaceHID=true in
  /etc/bluetooth/input.conf and restart the bluetooth service.
- updated from 18.04 -> 18.10

The bug is still there... Is there anything I can do to solve this bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All above attempts and restarting the computer and the devices didn't help.

The solution was to pull out the batteries and then press the `bluetooth` button on the mouse to make it discoverable. After this the keyboard was also recognized (without restarting it and even if it is a separate model and hasn't anything to do with the mouse).

Answer (score 0):

Try running this command first:

```
bluetoothctl remove <device>
```

and then:

```
bluetoothctl connect <device>
```