# Ubuntu 18.04 - bluetooth mouse random disconnection

Tags: 18.04, mouse, bluetooth

I'm experienced with constant and random mouse disconnect,
when connected the mouse and keyboard work perfectly fine,
I tried all the solutions described in these article:

- [Bluetooth mouse constantly disconnects and reconnects](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1065335/bluetooth-mouse-constantly-disconnects-and-reconnects)

but nothing seems to work.

```bsh
    dpkg --status bluez | grep '^Version:'
    Version: 5.50-0ubuntu0ppa1

    uname -a
    Linux XYZ 4.15.0-1066-oem #76-Ubuntu

    bluetoothctl devices
    Device 00:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX Logitech Tablet Keyboard IPD
    Device 00:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX Apple Magic Mouse A1296 3Vdc
```

Any suggestions are welcome :)

Comment: I've also had this issue with Geniue mouse and keyboard and with some other mouse. It have been making me mad and I've returned to wired mouse and keyboard. I don't really know if this issue applied only to Ubuntu.
But, have you tried this: https://askubuntu.com/a/1085778/925971

Comment: 1. `Set UserspaceHID=true in /etc/bluetooth/input.conf`

2. `Unpair everything,  pair <MAC>, trust <MAC>`


**doesn't work in my case**